# How to use REST linked service in web activity

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a web activity that passes data to a rest based API.
I use this in multiple places and want the web activity to use a rest linked service that has the base url and authorization for the api configured.

The Web activity however only lets me select a linked service reference, and im not sure what that is.
It doesnt let me use the linked services url as the base for the web activity url.

Is there a way i can use the rest linked service as the base url for the web activity?

Answer (score 0):

You can make your REST Linked Service dynamic (URL and other parameters) and then you can use those parameters in Web activity.

The Azure Data Factory pipeline can be parameterize. You need to parameterize each component of the pipeline like **Linked Service, Datasets and Activity.**

In **URL** option under **Settings** in Web Activity, can be a literal URL string, or **any combination of dynamic expressions, functions, system variables, or outputs from other activities.**

Once all the parameters are parameterized, you can use them in any activity and linked service. You can use the same parameters in REST Linked Service Base URL and also in Web Activity URL without any changes.

Refer the [third-party tutorial by datasavvy.me](https://datasavvy.me/2020/01/30/parameterizing-a-rest-api-linked-service-in-data-factory/) for **Parameterizing a REST API Linked Service in Data Factory.**